# Rearranging column/values in csv file based on input column order

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i need your help in unix/awk to order the data in csv file (comma separated file) to certain order given in another file.  my knowledge is limited on this.

example:  File to rearrange.

```html
PRODUCTCODE SITE    BATCHID LV1P_DESCRIPTION
PRD-0989    Static  BATCH01 Estract 
PRD-0990    Static  BATCH02 Xstract 
PRD-0991    Static  BATCH03 8stract 
PRD-0992    Static  BATCH04 errs
PRD-0993    Static  BATCH05 dgerrr
PRD-0994    Static  BATCH06 Narros
PRD-0995    Static  BATCH07 sef3r
```

and if pass input column order as [This could be stored in another file]

```html
PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE
```

then my output file should come as below

```html
PRODUCTCODE LV1P_DESCRIPTION    BATCHID SITE
PRD-0989    Estract     BATCH01 Static
PRD-0990    Xstract     BATCH02 Static
PRD-0991    8stract     BATCH03 Static
PRD-0992    errs    BATCH04 Static
PRD-0993    dgerrr  BATCH05 Static
PRD-0994    Narros  BATCH06 Static
PRD-0995    sef3r   BATCH07 Static
```

Comment: CSV? Where are the commas? Is this actually whitespace separated, with each column being a sequence of non-whitespace characters? I see the file of columns is CSV.

Comment: yes csv , comma separated file.

Comment: Please provide your **real** input and expected outputs. Those who want to help you need an easy way to copy-paste to do their own tests.

Comment: There are surprisingly few commas in your CSV file ......

Comment: `printf ".mode csv\n.headers on\n.import data.csv t\nselect $(<columns.csv) from t;" | sqlite3` or `.mode tabs` if the data is tab-separated rather than by commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

- your CSV is simple (no quoted fields containing commas, one line per record...),
- and each record has exactly the same number of fields,
- and you specify the desired output order with exactly the same number of fields,

you can try (with any POSIX `awk`, tested with GNU `awk` and the `awk` that comes with macOS, output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v o='PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE' '
  BEGIN {n=split(o,h)}
  NR==1 {print o; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) a[$i]=i; next}
  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s", $(a[h[i]]), i==n?"\n":OFS)}
' foo.csv
-| PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE
-| PRD-0989,Estract,BATCH01,Static
-| PRD-0990,Xstract,BATCH02,Static
-| PRD-0991,8stract,BATCH03,Static
-| PRD-0992,errs,BATCH04,Static
-| PRD-0993,dgerrr,BATCH05,Static
-| PRD-0994,Narros,BATCH06,Static
-| PRD-0995,sef3r,BATCH07,Static
```

1. Set comma as input and output field separators (`-F, -v OFS=,`).
2. Pass desired output  order as variable `o` (`-v o='...'`).
3. In `BEGIN` block split variable `o` on input fields separator, store the result in array `h` and the number of columns in variable `n`.
4. For the first line store in array `a` the fields as keys and the field numbers as values (`a[$i]=i`). Go to next line (`next`).
5. For the other lines print the `n` first fields in desired order (`$(a[h[i]])`), followed by the output field separator except the last that is followed by a newline.

If the desired output order is stored in the first line of another file, say `bar.csv`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  NR==1 {o=$0; n=split(o,h); next}
  NR!= FNR && FNR==1 {print o; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) a[$i]=i; next}
  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s", $(a[h[i]]), i==n?"\n":OFS)}
' bar.csv foo.csv
```

1. `NR==1` is true only for the first line of the first file.
2. `NR!= FNR && FNR==1` is true only for the first line of the second file.

Comment: thanks Renaud for the helps , im getting output with slightly different results.   'SITE' colums is getting some repeated values as below                                                                                                    PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE
PRD-0989,Estract,BATCH01,PRD-0989,Estract,BATCH01,Static

Comment: Did you check your input? Do you **always** have **4** columns separated by **3** commas, without any trailing comma at the end of the lines?

Comment: not always having 4 column but at the end of the line there wont be any commas which means if  7 column then 6 comma  and this pattern is going to be fixed

Comment: We cannot guess all the details. Please edit your question and provide realistic, relevant inputs and expected outputs. If you can have more or less than 4 columns, please clearly indicate that. A quick look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section could probably help improving your question.

Comment: Note that the `awk` script I suggest should work with any number of columns, as long as it is constant. How do you pass the expected order? Do you provide the exact same number of columns in this order as in the input CSV file?

Comment: Yes same order as i given in the question. i could see the script working if i add comma at the end of the input file [header and all rows],  it seems something related to comma. i will try to test with different input format and check. Scripts seems good, may be something related to data format.

Comment: This should be quite easy to debug, simply add some `print` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr get.tl columns data
PRODUCTCODE LV1P_DESCRIPTION BATCHID SITE
PRD-0989 Estract BATCH01 Static
PRD-0990 Xstract BATCH02 Static
PRD-0991 8stract BATCH03 Static
PRD-0992 errs BATCH04 Static
PRD-0993 dgerrr BATCH05 Static
PRD-0994 Narros BATCH06 Static
PRD-0995 sef3r BATCH07 Static
```

Files look like:

```
$ cat columns
PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE
$ cat data
PRODUCTCODE SITE    BATCHID LV1P_DESCRIPTION
PRD-0989    Static  BATCH01 Estract
PRD-0990    Static  BATCH02 Xstract
PRD-0991    Static  BATCH03 8stract
PRD-0992    Static  BATCH04 errs
PRD-0993    Static  BATCH05 dgerrr
PRD-0994    Static  BATCH06 Narros
PRD-0995    Static  BATCH07 sef3r
```

Code in `get.tl`:

```
(match (@colfile @datafile) *args*
  (awk
    (:inputs datafile)
    (:let col-indices)
    ((= nr 1) (let ((wanted-cols (flow colfile
                                   file-get-lines first (spl ",")))
                    (col-index-hash (hash-zip f 0)))
                (set col-indices (mapcar col-index-hash wanted-cols))))
    (t [apply prn (mapcar f col-indices)])))
```

It looks as if the data might have been tab separated, and the tabs got converted to spaces, with a tab width of four. To output tab-separated, we can add a `(:set ofs "\t")` clause to the `awk` macro.

Comment: Hi Kaz , thanks for the inputs. I'm new to TXR List, so wanted to check the usage in Linux. Do I need to install first in Linux environment. I'm familiar with awk and this package /utility is already enabled in my environment.

Comment: @Kaz: In your answer, the link to TXR Lisp is broken. Otherwise thumbs-up for providing such an original solution!

Comment: @Sumesh TXR is packaged by a few distros like NixOS, Guix, Alpine, Void, HomeBrew. The project itself provides some tarball [binaries](https://www.kylheku.com/txr-downloads) for a few platforms like Ubuntu and Windows.  It has low dependencies and isn't hard to build from source; just `./configure && make && make install`.

Comment: `(mapcar f col-indices)` is tricky. `f` is the fields parsed from the file, a list. It's being used as the function to map through. A list behaves as a mapping from numeric indices to items. `(mapcar '(A B C) '(0 0 0 2 1))` produces `(A A A C B)`.  The list `(A B C)` behaves like a function that maps 0 to `A`, 1 to `B` and 2 to `C`. This does not work in most Lisps, but TXR has things like this for succinct data munging.  In `(hash-zip f 0)` the integer `0` is expected to be an iterable sequence and is interpreted as integers starting from `0`. Also not in any dialect I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ head *file
==> input_file <==
PRODUCTCODE SITE    BATCHID LV1P_DESCRIPTION
PRD-0989    Static  BATCH01 Estract
PRD-0990    Static  BATCH02 Xstract
PRD-0991    Static  BATCH03 8stract
PRD-0992    Static  BATCH04 errs
PRD-0993    Static  BATCH05 dgerrr
PRD-0994    Static  BATCH06 Narros
PRD-0995    Static  BATCH07 sef3r

==> order_file <==
PRODUCTCODE,LV1P_DESCRIPTION,BATCHID,SITE
```

---

```bash
awk -F' *|,' '
    NR==FNR{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i] = i
        next
    }
    FNR==1{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b[i] = a[$i]
    }
    {
        for (i=1;i<=length(b);i++) printf " %s", $(b[i])
        print ""
    }
 ' order_file input_file | column -t
```

```
PRODUCTCODE  LV1P_DESCRIPTION  BATCHID  SITE
PRD-0989     Estract           BATCH01  Static
PRD-0990     Xstract           BATCH02  Static
PRD-0991     8stract           BATCH03  Static
PRD-0992     errs              BATCH04  Static
PRD-0993     dgerrr            BATCH05  Static
PRD-0994     Narros            BATCH06  Static
PRD-0995     sef3r             BATCH07  Static
```